# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf: Dynamically update value of attribute

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I would like to update the value of a Thymeleaf attribute after the page has been loaded, so that I can create a progress bar. I have a Java function which returns the progress of an algorithm as a percentage, and a Bootstrap progress bar.

```
<div class="progress md-progress" style="height: 10px;">
    <div id="progress" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" style="height: 10px;" th:style="'width:'+ ${value}+'%;'" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

My question is how can I update the value of the attribute "value" without having to refresh the page? I assume it'll have to be jQuery or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved in a number of ways, but you will basically need 2 components:

1. An API method on the server side that you can use to know the current progress value (E.g. a `@RestController`), or something that would push that progress over a websocket.
2. Something on the webpage side to either pull for that data (e.g. using JQuery, plain JavaScript, Vue, ...), or receive it in a push (e.g. websocket) fashion.

The easiest solution is probably a rest controller with plain JavaScript that periodically does an AJAX request and updates the progress bar.